# Cross-reference list is empty in Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, word-2010, cross-reference

I have been given a Word file (.docx) that has about 35 figures and tables. When I try to add a cross-reference I get an empty list like this:

[image]

I made sure that:

1) The figures and tables are actually captions. If I delete anyone of them, the rest get updated as expected.

2) Other cross-references already in the file works. They get updated correctly like in (1)

3) The document doesn't have any 'track changes'. This is apparently a problem for some people, so I did an 'accept all changes'. Doesn't seem to help unfortunately.

4) I tried copy all and paste into a new file.

5) I tried selecting all and F9.

I'm perplexed why this is happening. Anyone can help me find the root cause?

Comment: This would probably be better researched/posted on SuperUser. At the moment, it is not at all clear that there is a programming problem involved.

Comment: Thanks, I saw a word question in SO so I posted here. Will repost in SU.

Answer (score 4):

I know that it is probably late, but maybe it will help somebody else.

1. Select caption below table/picture
2. Right click and select Toggle field codes - the caption show the code in format like SEQ xxx xxx
3. Go to Insert -> Reference -> Caption and click on New Label button
4. Insert the text following after SEQ from point 2. E.g. Fig.
5. Save the new label.
6. Go to Insert -> Reference -> Cross Reference - select the inserted value from point 4 in the Reference type dropdown list. Now you should see all the values.

The answer is based on the following [link](http://www.doodgical.com/fix-use-cross-reference-to-reference-a-sequencelist-of-items-in-ms-word/comment-page-1/#comment-40347).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I cannot find Insert -> Reference -> Caption in Winword 2013. Any updates for this method?

Comment: This works, can confirm. In my case, I had to (re-)add the "Fig." label. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2013, instead of Insert>Reference>Caption, right click on a figure or table and select insert caption. A dialogue box including the option New Label will appear.

In my case, I think this issue arose because of changes in language. The tables are all captioned with the French Tableau, but in insert references, it had Table and a blank list.